# In adaptive signal processing, what does it mean for an arrow to go through a block?

Tags: control, signal-processing, theory

[image]

For example, in this case the FIR digital filter has an arrow going through it. This is common in the signal processing comunity but very unintuitive from a control perspective i.e. where is the arrow going to?

Can someone care to explain, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the output from the "adaptive algorithm" block controls something about the "Adaptive FIR Digital Filter" block.

It's similar to the symbol for a variable or controlled resistor

[image]

or capacitor

[image]